# How did Kruger survive a grenade blowing up his face when Carlyle and Delacourt died from less severe injuries?

Tags: elysium

In the film *Elysium* (2013), Kruger is able to be healed by the med bay after having his face blown apart.

He wasn't even rushed into the med bay straightaway either. How is the med bay after to fix Kruger when Carlyle (the CEO guy) and Delacourt (the woman politican) sustain less severe injuries and they're unable to be saved.

Also, why did Delacourt even allow Kruger to be fixed up since in her own words, before Kruger killed her that she had no need for him anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The movie [script](http://www.raindance.co.uk/site/picture/upload/Elysium_by_Neill_Blomkamp.pdf) makes the order of events pretty clear;

**Carlyle is shot in the head on Earth (page 65).**

In the time taken to get him to the nearest repair bay we can assume approx 30-45 mins have passed. During this time he's obviously died and he's evidently suffered brain trauma beyond the repair capabilities of the medbay. Also there's the issue of whether the (botched) data transfer has had any ill effects.

**Delacourt is killed by being slashed across the throat (page 107).**

Frey is with her and attempts to staunch the bleeding but the med-bots are unable to repair her wounds because she's locked into the isolation room by Rhodes. After a brief attempt to staunch the bleeding, she dies on the floor.

**Delacourt has Kruger repaired because she needs (trustworthy) muscle**

By this point she's improvising wildly but her intention is still to recover Max without alerting the authorities to the illegal data in his head. If he's successful then there's a fair chance she'll still be able to make herself President. Obviously he immediately kills her which would suggest that her plan is at least slightly flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Although his injuries were very severe, Kruger was not brain dead. So, the MedBay was able to heal him in time. Carlyle and Delacourt died before they could get to a MedBay, which can only heal injuries and cannot reverse death.